# RStudio Server doesn't find libraries for Macports R when building

Tags: macos, rstudio, macports, rstudio-server

I'm building the latest github version of rstudio-server to run on OSX Yosemite, but can't get it to find the macports R libraries when installing.

I run into a "Minimum R version (2.11.1) not found." error when I run
`cmake -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..`
but when I pass `-DRSTUDIOVERIFYR_VERSION=0` as well, I configure successfully and make it to about 44% before the build fails:

```
Rogers-iMac:build roger$ sudo make install
Password:
Scanning dependencies of target gwt_build
Buildfile: /Users/roger/projects/rstudio/src/gwt/build.xml
[...]
Scanning dependencies of target rstudio-r
[ 44%] Building CXX object src/cpp/r/CMakeFiles/rstudio-r.dir/RErrorCategory.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object src/cpp/r/CMakeFiles/rstudio-r.dir/RExec.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/roger/projects/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:17:
In file included from /Users/roger/projects/rstudio/src/cpp/r/include/r/RExec.hpp:30:
In file included from /Users/roger/projects/rstudio/src/cpp/r/include/r/RSexp.hpp:33:
/Users/roger/projects/rstudio/src/cpp/r/include/r/RInternal.hpp:43:10: fatal error: 'Rinternals.h' file not found
#include <Rinternals.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I was able to find `Rinternals.h` in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/PrivateHeaders/Rinternals.h` (*EDIT: also in* `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/include/Rinternals.h`), but how do I point the build configuration to this location?

*EDIT*: Additionally, I experienced another problem where the build failed at about 70% with the error
`/opt/local/lib/libR.dylib/Resources/R: not a directory`
`make[2]: *** [src/cpp/r/R/packages/library/manipulate/DESCRIPTION] Error 126`
Upon further investigation, `/opt/local/lib/libR.dylib/Resources/R` does not exist, because `/opt/local/lib/libR.dylib` is actually a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the RStudio cmake script not properly detecting a MacPorts R installation. To fix these problems:

1. Point `cmake` to the correct location of your R executable using `export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/opt/local/bin/R` (or whatever the location is for you), as described in [this RStudio Knowledge Base Article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R). This solves the problem with `cmake` failing to generate a configuration.
2. To solve the problems with `Rinternals.h` not being found, go into `build/CMakeCache.txt` and change the path of `LIBR_INCLUDE_DIRS` to reflect `Rinternals.h`'s actual location, as described in [this RStudio Support Forum Question](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200659347-Building-R-Desktop-in-Ubuntu).
3. Ensure that `LIBR_EXECUTABLE`, `LIBR_HOME`, and `LIBR_DOC_DIR` all point to the correct location. You can get the correct locations by doing `R.home(component="home")` (or `component="doc"`) in an R interactive prompt, as described on [this webpage](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/Rhome.html). This will solve the build error at 44%, and the additional error I had at 70-ish%.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the specifics of `cmake` but you can try

```
$ export CPATH=$CPATH:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/PrivateHeaders/
$ sudo make install
```

to tell the compiler to look for header files in the location where you found them.

Comment: I reconfigured, and this time I had no problems with using cmake. When building, the error persists.

Comment: This should work, but some older versions of clang don't support CPATH (see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8971), so try working around that (see my answer).

Comment: Hmm... actually it looks like I didn't actually solve the problem; when I wiped out my build folder of the install and started fresh, it came back with the error

Answer (score 0):

Add `-I /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/PrivateHeaders/` to the compiler's command line.

Alternatively, you can set `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` in the environment to tell the compiler where to search for additional headers when compiling C++ code.  You may also want to set `C_INCLUDE_PATH` for C if needed.

```
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/PrivateHeaders
$ make
```

Comment: So turns out I can't even get it to configure with cmake properly; I was just using the `-DRSTUDIOVERIFYR_VERSION=0` configuration. On a clean `cmake` I'm back to square one.

Comment: I found the solution, which was in a poorly documented environment variable called `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R`. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, though, so thank you very much.